# Microsoft ADFS IDP SAML Issue

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, shibboleth

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine, which has Active Directory Federation Services installed to allow it to act as an Identity Provider.  I have a Shibboleth Service Provider which is using my IDP to authenticate, however the artifact resolution binding does not appear to be working.

I can confirm that my ADFS configuration database is set up to use SQL server and the artifact resolution endpoint is enabled.  I have looked in the artifactstore database and there appears to be a SAML response generated and stored.  I have run this through a SAML validator and it is a valid response.  The error message that the Shibboleth side returns is:

Identity provider returned a SAML error during artifact resolution.

Error from identity provider:

Status: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester
When I check the ADFS event logs, the error reported is:

The artifact resolution request failed.

Additional Data 
Exception message: 
MSIS0018: The SAML protocol message cannot be read because it contains data that is not valid.

I have enabled ADFS tracing and this is the only message returned there also.  Can anyone help please?

Update - I have run the SAML Tracer while using Firefox and the request sent from the SP to the IDP is as follows (I have removed specifics):

```html
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://xxx.xxx.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact"
                    Destination="https://ccc.ccc.co.uk/adfs/ls/"
                    ID="_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    IssueInstant="2015-02-19T10:10:53Z"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                    Version="2.0"
                    >
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://xxx.xxx.com/shibboleth</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="1" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

There is no response sent via the browser, however ADFS is generating a SAML response and storing it in the adfs artifact database.  The response is as follows (specifics removed):

```html
<samlp:Response ID="_1xxxxxxxxxxx" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2015-02-19T10:11:05.391Z" 
 Destination="https://xxx.xxx.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" 
 InResponseTo="_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
 <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://ccc.ccc.co.uk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
 <samlp:Status>
  <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <Assertion ID="_dxxxxxxxxxxx" IssueInstant="2015-02-19T10:11:05.282Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
   <Issuer>http://ccc.ccc.co.uk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
     <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
     <ds:Reference URI="#_dxxxxxxxxxxx">
      <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
       <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxxxxxx=</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
     <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==</ds:X509Certificate>
     </ds:X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
   <Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" 
     NameQualifier="http://ccc.ccc.co.uk/adfs/services/trust" 
     SPNameQualifier="http://xxx.xxx.com/shibboleth">
     xxxxxxxxxxxx=
    </NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
     <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_1xxxxxxxxxxx" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-19T10:16:05.407Z" 
      Recipient="https://sp.cobweb.secure-dimensions.de/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/Artifact" />
    </SubjectConfirmation>
   </Subject>
   <Conditions NotBefore="2015-02-19T10:11:05.188Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-19T18:11:05.188Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
     <Audience>
      https://xxx.xxx.com/shibboleth
     </Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
   </Conditions>
   <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-02-19T10:11:03.766Z" SessionIndex="_dxxxxxxxxxx">
    <AuthnContext>
     <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>
    </AuthnContext>
   </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I have the response as a basic one with just the NameID and no attributes at the moment as I get the same error message regardless of whether they are there or not.
Thanks,

Fran

Answer (score -1):

Use Firefox and add the "SAML Tracer" add-on.

Then have a look at the SAML messages and see if there is anything obvious.

Or post them here (obfuscate any identifying stuff first).